# Move up history custom key in Julia REPL

Tags: julia

Is there a way to remap the "move up one line by searching with the preceding characters" operation (UP arrow by default) in Julia REPL?

I tried the key binding customization examples provided in the Julia REPL official documentation. But it does not seem to work the same way as the UP arrow key (or Ctrl+P by default). The default UP arrow key basically iterates backward in the command history using only commands that share the same prefix with the current command line input.